# I need to change the sorting mode numbers in drupal 7

Tags: sorting, drupal, drupal-7, numbers

I am having a problem with drupal 7. We have a content type named "resolutions", which represents sorted numbers: 1-10-2-20, etc. I would like to know how to add "0" to the numbers from "1 to 9" so they look like "01-02-etc". I tried to sort number module, but this doesn't work. If anyone could give me a solution, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Views to list your nodes, which I suspect you are, you should try the [Views Natural Sort](https://drupal.org/project/views_natural_sort) module.